# Is it possible to write a script relocating the "auto keying" button to Graph editor?

Tags: animation

How would I go about adding the Auto-key toggle button to the Graph Editor? The only reason I use the Timeline editor is because that button is located on it.

Comment: It can be done, but I don't have the time to work out the details.  Basically, you need to create a MT class and append it to the graph header.  It'll end up at the end of the header; but it's doable.

Answer (score 1):

My personal workaround is to keep the whole Timeline window as tiny as possible.

[image]

Comment: Alternative is to add the autokeying toggle as a quick favorite and not have the timeline visible at all.

Comment: Both are good workarounds, thanks guys.